# Why SurfaceView instead of View?

Tags: android, callback, surfaceview

Why is it util to use SurfaceView instead of View is SurfaceView if its a lower class? and once we are in SurfaceView why do we have to use the getHolder() and add a CallBack? Why do we have to use SurfaceDestroyed, SurfaceChanged and SurfaceCreated?

Please don't pass me the android link because is hard to understand it from there.

Comment: to extend SurfaceView in a class instead of View*

Example: 

public class MyClass extends SurfaceView{}

Comment: You can edit your question. You don't need to add code into a comment, where it is much harder to read.